# Is there a way to read non-String values from a properties file in Spring

Tags: spring, properties

I am trying to read a list of Long values from a properties file. How can I read it without doing any explicit type conversion.

I am trying to do something like this,

```
@Value("#{new Long.parseLong('${LongList}'.split(','))}")
List<Long> longListValues;
```

Thanks

Comment: So your property is of the form `LongList=123,456,789`?

Comment: Yes @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: I don't think you need anything special. Spring should be smart enough to do it for a variable of type `List<Long>`.